# Redirect all but not from a specific folder or its subfolder .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, codeigniter-2

I have written the following htaccess rewrite to redirect any request to the maintenance page named index.php

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
  RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Now I want a folder on which I'm fixing development files shoud be excluded from the above universal redirect to index.php. How can I write that condition. I already did it like:

```
 RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !=/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx/ 
 ### here xxxxxx-is the folder name
```

The htaccess inside my xxxxxx folder to exclude 'index.php' from url to make the url look pretty but now it gives me 404 on server

```
 # Turn on URL rewriting
 RewriteEngine On

 # If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then
 # you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
 # If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
 # let it as it is
 RewriteBase /xxxxxxxxx/

 # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
 RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

 # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

 # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
 RewriteCond $1        ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|resources|css|js|images)

 # No rewriting
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

 # Rewrite to index.php/URL
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index.php|excluded-folder/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry bro. It gives me 404. I have other htaccess inside that folder which contains codeigniter app. I wrote conditions in it to prevent index.php not be shown in the url? Should I edit the question for that?

Comment: If you have .htaccess inside `xxxxxx` then that folder is automatically skipped from root's `/index.php`

Comment: Does it mean that I have to put index.php on the url or I have to remove those .htaccess inside xxxxxx?

Comment: But if you remove `/xxxxxx/.htacess` your CI app wont work right?

Comment: What do u adice to do on this now?

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are getting with leaving folder `xxxxx` and its .htaccess as it is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47845/discussion-between-edam-and-anubhava)